# Task scheduler "Run whether user is logged on or not" issue to startup application

Tags: powershell

I have a .bat file that starts up a powershell script.
Within this powershell script, i startup PowerBI with a given database.
The powershell script waits till powerBI has been done starting up, and will then be exporting data to some datadump files.
Doing this manually works fine, and also when its on the task scheduler to run when user is logged on.

The moment i change this to "Run whether user is logged on or not" it doesnt work anymore.
The reason behind this, is that it seems that powershell is unable to start PowerBI and therefore there is no open data to query in the rest of the script.

So the positive side is it runs the bat and powershell just fine, only the powershell itself seems incapable to start powerBI.
Are there any solutions to this? should i for example use a different method to call the appliation to start?
currently the powershell snippit to start the app looks like this:

```
$PBIDesktop = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBIDesktop.exe"  
$template = "C:\LiveData\Data.pbix"
$waitoPBD  = 60   

$app = START-PROCESS $PBIDesktop $template -PassThru
log_message "Waiting $($waitoPBD) seconds for PBI to launch"
Start-Sleep -s $waitoPBD
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue. So, sharing my experience..

First of all, please verify couple of things.

1. Specify user account which will be used to invoke the job. Also, ensure that, the account have sufficient permission.
2. Don't forget to un-check the checkbox (as shown in screenshot) under Conditions Tab

[image: Specify the User Account]

[image: Uncheck this Power Checkbox]

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to work. I tried running it under the admin account on the server, as well as SYSTEM account. Both with the "run with highest privileges" checked as well. so far still all without any luck

Comment: How you are calling the PowerShell script from batch script. Did you tried scheduling the PowerShell script itself !

Answer (score 0):

Just found this one - sorry it took so long.

I had this totally nerve-wracking issue too.

The solution for me is to realize that the task scheduler is a very deep part of the OS.

That's why I have to grant access to the file, for the `computername$` (system name) on the file or folder containing the file to run.

Right-click on the file or folder -> Security. Select edit and add `[Name of your computer]$` and give the read and execute permissions.

That's the only way I can make it run.

But I hope you found the solution in the meantime.